# mysql query to avoid multiple queries

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  col1 VARCHAR(55),
  col2 VARCHAR(55),
  col3 VARCHAR(55),
  0101 VARCHAR(55),
  0202 VARCHAR(55),
  0303 VARCHAR(55)
);
```

now i want to fill the table with data returned from another query, this one for example :

```
 SELECT   col1, col2, col3, GROUP_CONCAT(col4)
 FROM     my_other_table
 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

now this query results in this line (and much more but for my case one line is enough) :

```
 col1     col2        col3      GROUP_CONCAT(col4)
 -------------------------------------------------
 FIB100   internet   1MEGAMAX       0202,0404
```

Now what i want to do is to check if in the concatenated values i have the column name of the NOT YET populated columns (0101 0202 0303) of my table my_table. IF true i want to put an X

like this :

Table : my_table after insertion

```
 col1     col2        col3       0101   0202    0303 
 -----------------------------------------------------
 FIB100   internet   1MEGAMAX             X
```

my question : is there any way to do this with the same query ??

Thank you

Comment: did u ever run your create table statement. I suppose,columns with numeric names are not created. Please change your column names in your question

Comment: My bad , you are right, actually columns do contain letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help you.

I've changed names  of columns (you can't use numbers as column's name)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (
  col1 VARCHAR(55),
  col2 VARCHAR(55),
  col3 VARCHAR(55),
  c0101 VARCHAR(55),
  c0202 VARCHAR(55),
  c0303 VARCHAR(55)
);

CREATE TABLE my_other_table (
  col1 VARCHAR(55),
  col2 VARCHAR(55),
  col3 VARCHAR(55),
  col4 VARCHAR(55)
);
```

then, the query is:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1,col2,col3,c0101,c0202,c0303)
    select col1, col2, col3, 
           if (GROUP_CONCAT(col4) like '%0101%' , 'X' , '') as c0101,
           if (GROUP_CONCAT(col4) like '%0202%' , 'X' , '') as c0202,
           if (GROUP_CONCAT(col4) like '%0303%' , 'X' , '') as c0303
    From my_Other_table
    group by col1, col2, col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Case statement

```
Select col1, col2, col3, 
case when 0101 then x else '' end as 0101,
case when 0202 then x else '' end as 0202,
case when 0303 then x else '' end as 0303 from table.
```

Vinit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF()` also

```
select if(emp_id=1,'X','') as test, emp_id from TABLE_NAME;
```